# how to add unique key using uuid in react js?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, key, unique, uuid

I read a comment from someone here in StockOverflow who talks about React keys and said that

'React expects STABLE keys, meaning you should assign the keys once and every item on your list should receive the same key every time, that way React can optimize around your data changes when it is reconciling the virtual DOM and decides which components need to re-render. So, if you are using UUID you need to do it at the data level, not at the UI level',

and I want to ask if anyone know how to apply this in a real code where we have for example a context component that have an array of objects and another component that maps through this array, how can we apply this using uuid() or any other package.

Comment: Usually the data comes from an API that has ids on the objects, and you use those ids as keys for your React list. What is your use case here?

Comment: supposing that the data doesn't have an id, and we need to explicitly add an id with a library

Comment: Then add the ids according to your needs and use case. Where are you stuck with this? The question/problem seems too speculative to be on topic here.

Comment: actually, I was looking for some articles about this, but I haven't found exactly what I need, so I decided to post here. well, I think Mario's answer is a good one for me, thank you ggorlen for your time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not a common requirement for you to generate id on FE, it happens some times, so using `uuid` is a really good way of doing that. It is easy and implementation is quick.

I made an example for you here how to do it:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { v1 } from "uuid";
import "./styles.css";

const items: { name: string; id?: string }[] = [
  {
    name: "Name1"
  },
  {
    name: "Name2"
  },
  {
    name: "Name3"
  },
  {
    name: "Name4"
  },
  {
    name: "Name5"
  },
  {
    name: "Name6"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState<{ name: string; id?: string }[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setItemList(items.map((item) => ({ ...item, id: v1() })));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {itemList.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          {item.name} - {item.id}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this example your array is empty at the beginning and after first `useEffect` gets populated by `items` with `uuid` generated `id`s:

[And code sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-uuid-with-react-n5it8)

Comment: ok thanks sir, I appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Please try and add some code example for your question so that someone that wants to help you does not write everything from scratch.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do it next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can install react-uuid

```
import React from 'react'
import uuid from 'react-uuid'

const array = ['one', 'two', 'three']

export const LineItem = item => <li key={uuid()}>{item}</li>

export const List = () => array.map(item => <LineItem item={item} />)
```

Or you can use crypto.randomUUID() directly without packages.